# Regex Referencing Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String and a Regex.

the string will look like `DH18`

and I have my regex `([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)` which splits up the letters and the words

I only want the digits, so that which is contained in the second curly brackets.  How do I go about referencing this.

I want a statement like

```
if ($1 == 18)
   blah;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a non-capturing group or a lookbehind for the part that you do not want:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)  // Non-capturing group
(?<=[a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*) // Lookbehind
```

Note that regex returns groups only as strings, even when the group represents a number. Therefore, the check `$1 == 18` needs to use `equals()`:

```
if (matcher.group(1).equals("18")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a non-capturing group at all? Wouldn't `[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]*)` suffice?

Comment: @shyam I assume that the letters part needs to be present for a match to be valid, otherwise there's no need for the OP to mention it at all.

Answer (score 1):

With `([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)` you have to pick `$2` instead of `$1` to get digits as $0 is the complete match, and capturing parts start from `$1` .

```
if($2.equals("18"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("DH18");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group()); //will print 18
    }
```